# textfield should not allow to enter after 6 numbers & Digits

Tags: javascript, php, magento

we are displaying textfield to enter zip code.

We want to validate with only numbers & 6 digits.

means after 6 digits, it should not allow to enter other digits, also it should not allow to enter any symbols or alphabets.

```
    <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" 
maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>
<button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
<div id="delivery-message"></div>
```

**script**

```
Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
        new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
            method: "get",
            parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                 var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                 $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                 
                 $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                 $('delivery-html').update(json.html);  
            }
        });
    });
```

i tried `class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-6 minimum-length-6 validate-digits"` but it didt worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the amount of characters and the type (digits) of the `input` with HTML5 attributes like so:

```html
<input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" maxlength="6" placeholder="ZIP Code" pattern="\d{6}" />
```

The `maxlength` restricts the maximum amount of characters for the `input` field.
The `pattern` restricts the type of characters which the `input` allows. In this case it is only valid if six digits are entered. However it seems that this is initially only validated upon submission of the form, not while typing.

More Information about the `input` field and the attributes can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

To restrict the entry of invalid characters you need to use JavaScript. A working example can be found here: http://codepen.io/michewl/pen/jrEQgd/

The JavaScript part uses jQuery to listen on the keydown-Event and prevents any non digit character to be inserted in the `input`.

You need to alter your HTML as follows:

```html
<input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" maxlength="6" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>" pattern="\d{6}"/>
<button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
```

And add the following JavaScript:

```html
<script>
    $("#zipcode").keydown(function(event) {
        return /\d/.test(event.key);
    });
</script>
```

Based on the link you postet in the comments above I assumed that jQuery is available.

Comment: please check now, i forgotten to add script

Comment: I do not see the script. And the input field does have a different `id` so the script has to be altered anyway. However there is a console output for the keydown-Event: `zipcode onkeypress worked`.
Please modify the HTML according to above, add the JavaScript and try it again. You may also need to change the JavaScript-Part `${"#zipcode"}` to `${"#estimate_postcode"}`.

Comment: i updated the question with script that we are using  before. also now you can see script gave by you in the page.

Comment: Sorry, there are still the attributes missing and my suggested script is still not in. The script you postet will not work with the page http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/seba-med-baby-powder-200g.html as there is no element `zipcode` which you select with `$('zipcode')`. Maybe you are messing up different websites?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code with your input box

```
maxlength="6" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" title="Invalid ZIP code"

<script>
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

And it should work .

Comment: it restricted to 6 digits, but allowing other  than digits.

Comment: i added like this : `<input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" 
   maxlength="6" pattern="[0-9]{6}" class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-6 minimum-length-6 validate-digits" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>`

Comment: Are you using html5. I doubt

Comment: sorry, no idea, we are using magento 1.9 version.

Comment: Ok. Then you can validate using jquery . onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Comment: Add this onKeyPress Function with html and inside script paste those lines.

Comment: can you please update the answer with both php and javascript code.

Comment: please check [here](http://stylebaby.com/umbrella-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113537/discussion-between-bikash-p-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).